# Client PHP calling .NET webservice keep session information

Tags: php, .net, soap, connection

I'm bulding a PHP client (I have already a C# client) as proof of concept. The PHP client will connect with the same .NET server using SOAP. As example I'm using the game blackjack.

Now first the C# client works perfect, but there is an issue in the PHP. After much debugging I found out that PHP always uses a new connection for every remote server call. This makes it impossible to program a game.

For example, I have a PHP file that just sets up the client like this (client.php):

```
try {
    $client = @new soapClient("http://localhost:8000/BlackJack/Service?wsdl",
        array(
            "trace" => 1,
            "exceptions" => 0,
            "cache_wsdl" => 0)
        );

} catch (Exception $e) {
    print 'Caught exception: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n";

}
```

Then in my main file (ill be using jQuery and ajax calls to load it dynamically but now im just testing) I have the following code (blackJackClient.php):

```
require_once("client.php");
$ini = ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled","0");
$BetAmountPost = 100;
    print_r($result = $client->buttonDeal_Click(array("BetAmount" => (string)$BetAmountPost))->buttonDeal_ClickResult);
    print_r($result = $client->PlayerMoney()->PlayerMoneyResult);
```

The first call will start a new game (Deal) and the player his bet amount (for example 100) gets subtracted from the total amount (1000). So what do I get returned in result is money = 900.

The following commando will ask what money I currently have, and one expects to get returned 900, but no instead I have 1000 (my starting amount).

So my question is how can I make it that all call's are made in 1 session so we still use the same connection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SOAP uses the HTTP protocol, and HTTP is stateless, there is no way to keep your connection open during the session of the game.
Instead, you should send your user's authentication with every request to the server.